# Use grepl to match certain words but only in specific contexts where other words must not occur

Tags: r, regex-lookarounds, grepl

Assuming this is my data...

```
mydata<-data.frame(text=c("There are books.","Books are bad.", "I like to read books."))
```

...how would I, using grepl, match rows in which "book(s)" occur, but "bad" doesn't (i.e. rows 1 and 3, but not row 2)?

I tried something like that with a negative lookahead...

```
grepl("book(s)?.*?(?!\\bbad\\b)", mydata$text, perl=T, ignore.case=T)
```

...but that didn't work as it also matches the second row. I assume that is because as soon as "book(s)" get detected, it returns "TRUE" and doesn't bother about whether or not "bad" co-occurs.

EDIT: Just to add this as a condition: I don't know anything about the specific structure of the string and the location of `book`s and `bad`s, but let's just assume `book(s)` comes first. Example: `"there are plenty of books, all of which are bad, but some I really like."`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using negative lookahead, we can do

```
grepl("^(?!.*bad).*books.*$", mydata$text, perl = TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

This ensures that `bad` is not present in `mydata$text` before checking for `books`.

Comment: Okay, that works if I know exactly where "book(s)" and "bad" are located in the string. And I guess it's my fault, because my questions wasn't very specific in that sense, but what if I do not no the location (i.e. end of beginning of the string)? Let's say there could be a string like `"apple banana books orange cherry bad strawberry"`. Do you know why my solution (`"book(s)?.*?(?!bad)"`) doesn't work?

Comment: @FabianHabersack `grepl("^(?!.*bad).*books.*$", "apple banana books orange cherry bad strawberry", perl = TRUE)` returns `FALSE` and that's what you expect right?

Comment: No because "book(s)" and "bad" co-occur in the same sentence or string. So what I would need is TRUE, and a grepl with which I can match "books" but avoid strings where "bad" appears (anywhere in the sentence).

Comment: @FabianHabersack sorry, its not clear to me. what is the preference "book" or "bad". If "bad" appears string would be `FALSE` or if "book" appear string would be `TRUE`? Which of these condition is correct?

Comment: 1.) "Book(s)" must appear for it to be TRUE, but only if 2.) "bad" does NOT appear anywhere in the same sentence. Does that make sense?

Comment: so other way to put it if "bad" appears anywhere in the sentence then it becomes `FALSE`. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct! ... although the first condition is also crucial, namely that "book(s)" must appear...

Comment: so why in your above example you say answer should be `TRUE` when there is "bad" in there? `grepl("^(?!.*bad).*books.*$", "apple banana books orange cherry bad strawberry", perl = TRUE)` returns `FALSE`.  If you remove "bad" from there it returns `TRUE` because "books" is present. `grepl("^(?!.*bad).*books.*$", "apple banana books orange cherry strawberry", perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. It's totally my fault, but I thought that because there is a `^`-sign, it only matches "bad" at the beginning of the string and because there is a `$`-sign, it only matches strings where "bad" is located at the end...

Comment: no..`^` is separate and has got nothing to do with `bad`. `(?!.*bad)` is negative lookahead which ensures that there is no word "bad" in the string, if it finds "bad" it returns `FALSE` and returns `TRUE` if it finds "books" in the string.

Comment: OK great. So if I understand it correctly, `^` and `$` are just there to tell R which of the two conditions to check first and which to check second, correct? So in other words: `^[firstcondition]...[secondcondition]$`.

Comment: not exactly. If you noticed it also works without `^` and `$`, `grepl("(?!.*bad).*books.*", "apple banana books orange cherry strawberry", perl = TRUE)`.  As we are using negative lookahead for "bad" it checks for "bad" first and later for "books".

Comment: OK thanks for your help and sorry to bother you again, but why would it not work if the order was reversed: namely, if we had the "books"-conditions first and the "bad"-condition after...?

Comment: @FabianHabersack  I think that it because if you keep "books" first then preference is given to "books" first and then it checks for "bad". So if "books" is present then it would return `TRUE` by default.

Answer (score 1):

An easier option is

```
grepl('book(s)?', mydata$text) & !grepl('\\bbad\\b', mydata$text)
```

Comment: Right, that would work, too. But is there a way to combine these two into one?

Comment: @FabianHabersack. Is is posssible, but would have ssome edge cases and would not be a clean implementation